# How to add values ​between hours

Tags: r, ggplot2, time

I have code that breaks down hours with corresponding values ​​into quarters of an hour.
Unfortunately, when broken down into quarters of an hour, the values ​​are identical for the entire hour.
After adding quarters of an hour, I would also like to add values ​​between the original hours so that the graph is smooth and not sharp. How to do it, average it, interpolate it?

```
df <- data.frame(
  h = 0:23,
  x = c(22, 11, 5, 8 , 22, 88, 77, 7, 11, 5, 8 , 22, 88, 77, 11, 5, 8 , 22, 88, 77, 11, 5, 8 , 22))

library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
  data.frame(h = rep(df$h, each = 4),                             # quadruplicate rows
             x = rep(df$x, each = 4)) %>%                         # quadruplicate rows 
  mutate(h.1 = str_pad(h.1, width = 2, side = "left", pad = "0"), # add leading '0'
         qu = paste0(h.1, c(":00", ":15", ":30", ":45"))) %>%     # create quarters
  select( - c(h,x)) %>%                                           # deselect obsolete cols
  rename(c("h" = "h.1", "x" = "x.1"))  

 df %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(qu, x), color = "red", size = 2) +
  labs(x= "", y = "",
       title = "Example")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I make a "decimal hour" variable to simplify the calculations. We can also use `hms::hms()` to define a timestamp that ggplot2 can understand. I use `base:approx` here to interpolate between hourly points.

```
df2 <- df %>%
  tidyr::uncount(4) %>%  # make 4 copies of each row
  mutate(h_dec = h + (0:3)/4,
         h_time = hms::hms(hours = h_dec),
         x = x * c(1, NA, NA, NA),  # this is to make non-hourly into NA,
                                    # so that approx only uses hourly
         x_interp = approx(x = h, y = x, xout=h_dec)$y)
         
df2 %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(h_time, x_interp), color = "red", size = 2) +
  labs(x= "", y = "",
       title = "Example")
```

[image]

Comment: That's what I meant, thank you. :)
The time format has also changed, for example a date with time:
2021-04-13 01:00:00

Could this be modified in the code on
2021-04-13 01:00, 2021-04-13 01:15, 2021-04-13 01:30, 2021-04-13 01:45, ... ?

Comment: Try `h_time = lubridate::ymd_hm(paste("2021-04-13", h, c(0, 15, 30, 45)))`

Comment: Using this code, I have the same time all the time, unfortunately the quarters of an hour do not change. df2 <- df %>%
  tidyr::uncount(4) %>% # make 4 copies of each row
  mutate(h_dec = datetime+ (0:3)/4) Quarters of an hour are not added.

Comment: When I put my suggested line `h_time = lubridate::ymd_hm(paste("2021-04-13", h, c(0, 15, 30, 45))),` in place of or after `h_time = hms::hms(hours = h_dec),` I get the expected result with an April 13 based x axis.

Comment: I would also like to add an approximation for the adjacent columns, let's call it rrr_interp.
How to do it?

Comment: I think you'd add after `x_interp = approx(x = h, y = x, xout=h_dec)$y)`: `%>% mutate(rrr_interp = approx(x = rrr, y = x, xout=h_dec)$y)` where `rrr` is the adjacent column you have now.